# Cannot use rosdep to install image_view in ros hydro

Tags: ros, rosdep, ubuntu, image-view, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*Hi all , I am running Ubuntu 13.04 and I cannot install image_view using rosdep install image_view. It returns the following :

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query

Missing resource image_view

ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros

ROS path [1]=/home/nyan/catkin_ws/src

ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/hydro/share

ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks

Can anyone help me to solve this error? Thanks a lot in advance. *

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143596/cannot-use-rosdep-to-install-image_view-in-ros-hydro/) by [manaXmizery](https://answers.ros.org/users/9931/manaxmizery/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
If you have already initialised and updated rosdep with:

sudo rosdep init

&

rosdep update
and it still doesn't work 
Try using 
"sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-image-view ".

---

Originally posted by [Leyonce](https://answers.ros.org/users/13066/leyonce/) with karma: 97 on 2014-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1